# Can I use a SD wi-fi adapter in my EOS Rebel T5i?

Tags: canon, wifi-sd

I have a Canon T5i that I'd like to use for long-term time lapse photography.   Can I use one of the cheapie "SD Wifi adapter" cards for sale on Amazon to save the pictures to an external location (say, on one of my PCs) or is there a better way to do this?   I'd just like to set up the camera and have it click away, one picture per minute, for about a month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your camera is going to need to be powered from an [external source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0092F974E) for a time period covering anywhere approaching a month, you might as well also connect it directly to a computer via the USB port and use [*tethered shooting*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tethering).